# Does disabling Sitecore XDB and Tracking help in improving Site Performance?

Tags: xdb, tracking

Can disabling Sitecore XDB and tracking help in improving Site Performance ?
What all can be functionalities/ features can be impacted if we disable them ?

Comment: are you not using analytics? Are you using XP?

Answer (score 2):

Disabling Sitecore XDB and Tracking is Sitecore's **CMS-only mode**. In CMS-only mode, any functionality that depends on data collection will be unavailable and a number of applications will not run. In CMS-only mode, the Sitecore XP applications and functionality are classified as:

**Fully compatible** -The following features will run in CMS-only mode without any changes:

- Content editing in the Experience Editor
- Device detection
- IP Geolocation detection
- Commerce Connect

**Compatible with limited functionality** - The following features will run in CMS-only mode with limitations:

- Campaign Creator – runs without analytics functionality.
- Personalization – in-session personalization works, while personalization based on historical data is unavailable.
- Web Forms For Marketers. (lower versions only)
- Sitecore Forms – runs without analytics functionality.

**Incompatible** - The following features are incompatible with CMS-only mode:

- Content testing
- Email Experience Manager
- Experience Analytics
- Experience Explorer
- Experience Profile
- Federated Experience Manager
- List Manager
- Path Analyzer
- Segmentation
- Marketing Automation

Now based on your website's requirements and Sitecore's functionalities you are using, you can disable the Sitecore XDB and tracking and it will definitely improve the performance of your site as Sitecore will not collect lots of information from end-user. Also if you just need the CMS-only mode it will give you a benefit in your license cost as well (no need to purchase xDB licenses)(You need to speak to your local Sitecore representative or partner for this).
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/102/sitecore-experience-platform/cms-only-mode-compatibility.html

Comment: great help, that was informative.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore `Analytics/Experience Database (xDB)` is something you may not need locally or on QA, so disabling it may increase Sitecore’s performance. One reason you may want to disable `xDB` locally is if you just need to fix front end look and feel issues, xDB is not required in this case. xDB uses MongoDB, so if you do not have MongoDB setup locally and want to avoid a bunch of errors in the Sitecore log, disable xDB.

Here is the Sitecoe Document that shows the features compatibility when it is disabled.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/sitecore-xp-feature-compatibility-when-the-xdb-is-disabled.html

Comment: Hi @sumit Bhatia, thanks for reply. Actually I am working on SItecore 10.1 also the requirement is to disable it on Prod as we don't use reporting through sitecore. So can this be helpful in increasing website performnace for end user?

Comment: @samridhisachdeva I would say disable it if you don't need something mainly on Prod. It will stop services that collect the information on the website and for this, it runs services in backed.

Comment: ok, Thank you:)